# Change variable value and store it into an other variable

Tags: bash

```
for file in /path/path/???????????_aa.fasta.aln.1; do name=$($file|sed 's/.1//g'), echo mv ${file} $sup  ; done
```

The idea of this code is to change the `???????????_aa.fasta.aln.1` file name into `???????????_aa.fasta.aln`

So I had the idea to change the `$file` value by deleting the `.1` and then storing it into the variable `name`, then I just echo the ancient name `$file` and the new name `name`. Then I paste all the code generated.

But it does not work.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: `$file|sed 's/.1//g'` will *execute* the contents of `$file`. You probably meant something like `printf "$file"|sed 's/.1//g'`. (And then `mv "$file" "$name"`, not `… $sup`.)

Comment: …but then again you don’t need `sed` (and note that the pattern you use with `sed` matches more than just `.1` at the end); simple parameter expansion would suffice, e.g: `name="${file%.1}"` (Or even `mv "$file" "${file%.1}"`.)

Comment: But my files already have .1 at the end, the aim is to remove it.

Comment: Yes. That’s what all of my examples above do.

Comment: ok but how do I store the "$file"|sed 's/.1//g' part without .1 into the name variable?

Comment: Like you do with `name=$(…)`. But that’s not the issue with your code.

Comment: I got it ! Thank you for your help.